# Сформировать возрастающий массив из чётных чисел

Tags: c#

Уважаемые, вопрос задачи в теме, вот код:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] arr = new int[5];
        Work ob = new Work();
        ob.Go(arr);
        for(int i =0; i< arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Work
{
    int temp = 0;
    public void Go(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0) {
                arr[i] = temp;
                continue; }
            if((i % 1) == 0) {
                arr[i] = (temp = temp + 2); }
        }
    }
}
```

Задача решена верно, но не понимаю почему верный результат. Ведь на третьем шаге итерации массив должен заполниться нулём(по второму индексу). Т.е., индекс 2 НЕ пройдёт проверку на чётность и конструктор по умолчанию заполнит его нулём. Но этого не происходит. Почему?

Comment: Не *нулём*, а текущим значением переменной `temp`. Которая была увеличена на `2` на предыдущем шаге (`temp = temp + 2`).

Comment: Откройте для себя отладчик. Он сделан для того, чтобы не гадать как же работает программа, а посмотреть как же именно она работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте начнем с переменной `tenp`, объявленной в классе `Work` и используемой в методе `Go`

Ее начальное значение равно 0.

```
int temp = 0;
```

В методе `Go`для каждого значения переменной `i` за исключением значения 0 переменная `temp` увеличивается на 2

```
        if((i % 1) == 0) {
            arr[i] = (temp = temp + 2);
```

и последовательно принимает значения 2, 4, 6 и.т.д. Эти значения присваиваются элементам массива

```
            arr[i] = (temp = temp + 2);
```

Кстати сказать можно было бы это выражение написать, не используя скобки

```
            arr[i] = temp = temp + 2;
```

так как операторы присваивания группируются справа налево.

Имейте в виду, что любое целое положительное число при деление на 1 дает остаток равный 0. Поэтому выражение в данном `if`-предложении

```
        if((i % 1) == 0) {
```

всегда истинно. Никакой проверки на четность в цикле нет.:) Условие проверки на четность выглядит как

```
        if((i % 2) == 0) {
               ^^
```

Метод `Go` можно было бы записать значительно проще, а не так вычурно. Например

```
public void Go(int[] arr)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ ) arr[i] = 2 * i;
}
```

Или если использовать переменную `temp`

```
public void Go(int[] arr)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ ) 
    {
        arr[i] = temp;
        temp += 2;
    }
}
```

И нет никакой необходимости делать его нестатическим методом класса. Лучше было бы записать

```
public static void Go(int[] arr) { /*...*/ }
       ^^^^^^
```

Конечно в этом случае и переменная `temp`, если она используется в методе, также должна быть объявлена как статическая переменная. Тем не менее в том контексте, как вы показали использование кода, надобности в этой переменной вообще нет.